How to Retrieve the Entry Title in a Strapi Plugin?
I am currently building a plugin that will be able to modify the content types.
I would like to get the Entry title, which can be accessed and edited here, for example, for the content type “Type”: http://localhost:1337/admin/content-manager/collection-types/api::type.type/configurations/edit.
Currently, the entry title is set to “Test entry title”, but I don’t find any command to get it via the plugin as we can do to get the attributes of a content type with this command “strapi.contentTypes”.
My project is in TypeScript.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
